# How can I format data from gspread api into Google Sheets

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am new to python (and programming in general). I am currently working on automating a data entry aspect of my job. So far I have figured out how to sort out the data I want from a csv with pandas, and load it into the appropriate area of a google spreadsheet with the gspread api. My problem is that the csv data dumps into a single cell of the speadsheet. How can I make have it enter across the row of cells? I have tried every parameter of the .appendrow() function.

Thanks so much - Owen K

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("/Users/macbook/Documents/Atom Projects/Sheets1/creds.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/macbook/Documents/Atom Projects/Sheets1/report.csv')#, index_col = '(Child) ASIN')

Luna = (df['(Child) ASIN'] == 'B0716JTGSX')
LU = df[Luna].to_csv()

print(LU)
bick4 = client.open("Test Sheet") .worksheet('bick 4')
bick4.append_row([LU])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values of `LU = df[Luna].to_csv()` to each cell in the Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values using Sheets API.

For this, how about this answer?

### Modification points:

- In this case, a list is created from `df[Luna]` and the list is put to the Spreadsheet using gspread.

I propose the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the value of `df[Luna]` is put to the Spreadsheet using the method of `values_update`.

#### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
spreadsheet = client.open('Test Sheet')
sheet_name = 'bick 4'

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/macbook/Documents/Atom Projects/Sheets1/report.csv')#, index_col = '(Child) ASIN')
Luna = (df['(Child) ASIN'] == 'B0716JTGSX')
LU = df[Luna]

values = [LU.columns.values.tolist()]
values.extend(LU.values.tolist())
spreadsheet.values_update(sheet_name, params={'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'}, body={'values': values})
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the value of `df[Luna]` is put to the Spreadsheet using the method of `values_update`.

#### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
spreadsheet = client.open('Test Sheet')
sheet_name = 'bick 4'

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/macbook/Documents/Atom Projects/Sheets1/report.csv')#, index_col = '(Child) ASIN')
Luna = (df['(Child) ASIN'] == 'B0716JTGSX')
LU = df[Luna]

values = LU.values.tolist()
spreadsheet.values_append(sheet_name, params={'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'}, body={'values': values})
```

### References:

- [values_update](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_update)
- [values_append](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_append)